# App crashes at launch because of realm (RLMIsObjectSubclass) - Swift iOS RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, realm

My app crashes at launch for like 1-2 percent of users everyday due to `RLMIsObjectSubclass`.

```
BOOL RLMIsObjectSubclass(Class klass) {
    return RLMIsKindOfClass(class_getSuperclass(class_getSuperclass(klass)), RLMObjectBase.class);
}
```

Exact line where the issue is shown.

I tried reproducing the issue by some changes but it seems it's randomly generated or internally due to Realm.

Comment: This looks like a mix of Swift and Objective-C. Does it even compile?

Comment: Yeah @soundflix it does, It it the internal function line where it shows the crash in Framework file

Comment: If this is a bug in a third party library, there is nothing we can do here to resolve it. You should file a bug report with MongoDB Realm. However, duplicating the issue is critical to resolution and it's possible the calling code could be causing the issue and that should be included in the question along with your XCode and OS version as well as the version of Realm and cocoapods if being used. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Update the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/5618

Comment: Yeah I have seen it @soundflix

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code provided in the question is from a third party library. Nothing can be on SO to resolve the issue so the best course of action is to file a bug report with that third party to bring attention to the issue.

Comment: There is already an issue filed in the library from like couple of years, I have not found any helpful answer that is why I raised a question to the community. @Jay

Comment: Completely understood - however, this forum (SO) is for help with code *you* write, not for assistance with a third party library as there is absolutely nothing we can do to address it or even fix it. Along those same lines one of the recommendations here is to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and that one line of code doesn't meet that criteria. Perhaps if there was more context in the question it would lead to a better understanding of the issue and maybe even a workaround.